# How to force input type text within span width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 input text field.

Their css define them as width:100%

I previously use table and split it into 2 td cell and thus I define the cell as 60% : 40% respectively  and I place the input type text field into the 2 td and the sizing works fine

But then I removed the table due to some alignment issue.

I prefer to use span so I did a

```
<span style="width:60%"> INPUT TYPE TEXT</span>
<span style="width:40%"> INPUT TYPE TEXT</span>
```

But the issue is the input text is taking the whole 100% width and not stay within the span.

How do I make it get the same look as if its in a table cell.

Thanks

Comment: Please show complete code needed to replicate your problem. We have no idea what your css looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block` and `float:left` properties like,

```
<span style="width:60%;display:inline-block;float:left"> INPUT TYPE TEXT</span>
<span style="width:40%;display:inline-block;float:left"> INPUT TYPE TEXT</span>
```

```html
<div style="width:100%">

  <span style="width:60%;display:inline-block;float:left;"> INPUT TYPE TEXT</span>
  <span style="width:40%;display:inline-block;float:left;"> INPUT TYPE TEXT</span>
</div
```

Answer (score 0):

Span elements doesn't contain the full width i.e. 100% width because inline element cannot have the width. You need to set display:inline-block; or use float:left; on them:

```
span{
  float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7wzuetk9/